# prove or disprove if a number is irrational

Tags: irrational-numbers, rational-numbers

Prove or disprove :

[image]

I'm pretty sure this isn't true yet i can't find a counter example.
Thanks in advance !

Comment: Have you tried some simple values for $x$? How about $x=2$?

Comment: What if $x=2$??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes when trying to prove/disprove an "if...then" statement, it's useful to quickly check if the [contrapositive](http://www.regentsprep.org/regents/math/geometry/gp2/lcontrap.htm) is any easier.

In this case, the contrapositive is:

> If $x$ is rational, then $x^{1/3}$ is rational.

Is that true?

Answer (score 0):

HINT:  How about $x=2,3,4,5,6$?